# Create new column based on existing column that manipulates the characters based on data type within this to display new characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query that changes characters in an existing column to a new column based on the data type of each character. For example, if it is a letter, change it to an 'L'. If it is a number, change it to 'N' and if it is a special character, change it to an 'S'. Below shows clearer examples of what I would like as the output:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
abcdefg    LLLLLLL
12345      NNNNN
abc123     LLLNNN
a1b2z8     LNLNLN
yre!£456   LLLSSNNN
!???       SSSS
```

A few points to add:

- Column A is the original column. There is no pattern in which characters appear in and they can be any number of characters
- Column B is the desired outcome.
- When I mention special characters, I mean any character that is not a number/letter.

Sorry if this does not make sense, any questions and I will try and make it clearer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your sqlserver support TRANSLATE?

Comment: @CaiusJard It does not

Comment: What version are you running? (`SELECT @@version`)

Comment: Oof.. Think you might be looking at a row generator then, cross joining each string with the rowgen, substringing on rownumber, using isalpha/isnumeric or case asc() when to give the output, and then a string_agg style hack (stuff/xml)  to put it all together. Are you averse to creating a UDF for it, or possible a .NET function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make own function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPattern]
(
    @input NVARCHAR(2000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar NVARCHAR(2000) = '';
    DECLARE @i INT = 0, @Len INT, @c NCHAR(1);
    SELECT @Len = LEN(@input);

    WHILE (@i < @Len)
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1;
        SELECT @c = SUBSTRING(@input, @i, 1);

        IF @c BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' BEGIN SET @ResultVar = @ResultVar + 'L' END
        ELSE IF @c BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' BEGIN SET @ResultVar = @ResultVar + 'L' END
        ELSE IF @c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' BEGIN SET @ResultVar = @ResultVar + 'N' END
        ELSE BEGIN SET @ResultVar = @ResultVar + 'S' END;
    END
    
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

And next you just use it:

```sql
SELECT ColumnA, [dbo].[GetPattern](ColumnA) AS ColumnB FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly way:

```
WITH rg (rn) AS (
   SELECT 1 AS rn
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.rn + 1 AS rn
   FROM   rg a
   WHERE  a.rn < 99
),
example as(
  select 'azAZ19%!' as str
),
prepro AS (
SELECT 
  str, SUBSTRING(str, rn, 1) as chr, ASCII(SUBSTRING(str, rn, 1)) as ascii, rn
FROM
  example
  INNER JOIN rg ON rn <= LEN(str) 
),
postpro as (
select 
  str,
  rn,
  CASE 
    WHEN ascii BETWEEN 48 and 57 THEN 'N'
    WHEN ascii BETWEEN 65 and 90 THEN 'L'
    WHEN ascii BETWEEN 97 and 122 THEN 'L'
    ELSE 'S' END as lns
FROM prepro
)

SELECT DISTINCT
  str,
  (
    SELECT ',' + p.lns
    FROM postpro p
    WHERE p.str = x.str
    ORDER BY p.rn
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) as lns
FROM postpro x
```

I'd make a CLR

As to how this works:

The first query, `rg`, just generates numbered rows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
99
```

CROSS joining that to your data (let's use `az09`) gives the string data repeated:

```
1 az09
2 az09
3 az09
4 az09
5 az09
...
99 az09
```

We limit the rows to the length of the string:

```
1 az09
2 az09
3 az09
4 az09
```

Now we cut the string up 1 char at a time using the row number as the start index

```
1 az09 a
2 az09 z
3 az09 0
4 az09 9
```

Now we get the ascii number of the cut string

```
1 az09 a 65
2 az09 z 97
3 az09 0 48
4 az09 9 57
```

Then case when the ascii number to make L N S etc

```
1 az09 a 65 L
2 az09 z 97 L
3 az09 0 48 N
4 az09 9 57 N
```

Then we use a typical hack needed to aggregate strings over rows in 2016 (string_agg would do this if we had a modern db) with FOR XML - basically prepares an xml document of the results (like `<a>L</a><a>L</a><a>N</a><a>N</a>') without any of the tags, so it's just` LLNN`, repeated for every row:

```
1 az09 a 65 L LLNN
2 az09 z 97 L LLNN
3 az09 0 48 N LLNN
4 az09 9 57 N LLNN
```

Then if we just get the distinct `az09` and `LLNN`. The end

And it's horrific, on so many levels. Do please seek another way, like a C# function!

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. Will see if there is a cleaner way :)